# Why is a member template from private base class introduced with a using declaration inaccessible?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, compiler-errors, clang

Consider the following (artificial) example:

```
class A {
 public:
  template <typename T>
  class C {};
};

class B : private A {
 public:
  using A::C;
};

int main() {
  B::C<int> c;
}
```

It compiles successfully with both GCC and Clang, but Visual C++ 2010 gives the following error:

> test.cpp(13): error C2247: 'A::C' not accessible because 'B' uses 'private' to inherit from 'A'

Is this a bug in Visual C++ or this code is indeed invalid?

If `C` is not a template, the code compiles on all compilers.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294422/template-private-inheritance-in-vc10-is-not-accessible

Comment: I'm going to go with VC bug.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks for the link. It looks somewhat related indeed. Too bad the answers there don't say which compiler is correct.

Comment: @T.C. I also think so although it might be as well a gap in the standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[namespace.udecl]/p18:

> The alias created by the *using-declaration* has the usual
>   accessibility for a *member-declaration*.

Not much to say here. The name `B::C` is publicly accessible, and the code is well-formed. Just another MSVC bug.