# Making one of the inherited protected members private

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
class A
{
protected:
    int m_a;
    int m_b;
};

class B: public A
{
};
```

In class B i want to make `m_a` private. 
Does the following the correct way to do it

```
class B:public A
{    
private:
    int m_a;
};
```

Won't this result in 2 copies of `m_a` ?

Comment: The answer to this question here may also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804880/in-c-what-is-the-scope-resolution-order-of-precedence-for-shadowed-variab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `m_a` in `class B` **shadows** that of `class A`. It is a different data member, so class B actually has three `ints`: `A::m_a`,  `A::m_b` and `B::m_a`. The way to get private access to `m_a` in `B` is to "use" `A::m_a` privately in `class B`:

```
class A {
  int m_a;
};

class B:  public A {    
    using A::m_a;
};

class C : public B {
  void foo() { 
    m_a++; // ERROR!
  }
};
```

Comment: If that's the case, we would be getting redeclaration error is that right ? But I don't seem to get.

Comment: Not at all. but it does isolate m_a to B-code to be the one declared in B. The one in A is hidden from that point on unless class-resolved (A::m_a or ::m_a)

Comment: No, it isn't a re-declaration: `A::m_a` and `B::m_a` are separate members in each instance of `B`. The name lookup rules may be confusing, though.

Comment: @KodeWarrior if you want to see name hiding in action, declare a function ``void foo()`` in ``class A``, then an ``int foo`` in ``class B``.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to adjust the access control of a member is with a [`using` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084801/c-using-declaration-scope-and-access-control):

```
class B: public A {    
private:
    using A::m_a;
}
```

Just writing `int m_a;` would indeed result in two copies of `m_a`, and a derived class would be able to access `A`'s copy of `m_a` by writing `A::m_a`.

Comment: However, deriving `class C`  from `B`, you can still access `m_a` by explicitly qualifying it with `A::m_a`.

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich not with a conformant compiler; see e.g. http://liveworkspace.org/code/9ac3b1e42038bdd8cb5662fff0aa5753

Comment: As the saying goes, "protect against Murphy, not Machiavelli". If a class client successfully circunvents the safeguard using `A::m_a` and things go awry, well, just deserts.

Comment: @CraigNelson C++11 isn't required here. Just a C++03 conformant compiler.

Comment: No kidding. All this time.. those *were* the droids I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code create three int storages in the class B.

The declaration of m_a creates a new variable - there is no redeclaration problem in c++ here as the declarations are in different scopes, more specifically A::m_a is not the same as B::m_a.